# date difference in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have dates in 2 tables. Table `student` is as below:

```
ID|Name|Examdate
1  John 01/10/2015
2  Fred 11/12/2014
```

Table `retake` as below:

```
ID|RetakeDate
1  02/10/2016
2  05/11/2015
```

The IDs in `retake` relate to the students' IDs in `student`, i.e. they are the same.

I am trying to create another table where only students who have taken a retake after 12 months or more exist. The difference between `examdate` and `RetakeDate` needs to be >= 12months.

How do I achieve this?

There could be multiple rows in both tables for the same student. There will be multiple rows on both tables, as this will allow me to see how many times they have taken a retake and how many times an exam. At this moment in time I don't want to see if the retake is for the latest exam. I just want to see how many retakes they have taken all together.
End result should be comparing each Exam date with Retake date. Some more explanation:

> Q: So  if a student has dates in 2012, 2013, 2014 and then 2 retakes in 2016?
>
> A: There should 3 rows in the result (one for each date)
>
> Q: What if it's three exams – in 2012, 2013, 2014 – and (a) two retakes – in 2014 and 2016? or (b) one retake – in 2014? What should be expected as the result in each of those cases?
>
> A: It doesn't matter. As long as the (a) retake was taken after 12 months or more, they should appear in the result.

Comment: You could try this (suspiciously similar) question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303033/sql-date-calculations

Comment: This question has consumed too much user & moderator time already (on multiple sites). I am placing this question on hold until it is clarified (in the question body, not comments).

Comment: "12 months or more" after the first exam? Last exam? Any exam? How do we know which exam the retake was for?

Answer (score 2):

This query will return the times a student retook an exam after more than 12 months from the first take:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name)
FROM student, retake
WHERE student.ID = retake.ID
AND RetakeDate::date - '12 months'::interval >= Examdate::date
GROUP BY Name
```

It subtracts 12 months from `RetakeDate` and checks if the resulting date is greater or equal to `Examdate`.

This query works too:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name)
FROM student, retake
WHERE student.ID = retake.ID
AND age(RetakeDate::date, Examdate::date) >= '12 months'::interval
GROUP BY Name
```

The function `age(timestamp, timestamp)` is documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

### ATTENTION

Be aware that those two queries can give different results for periods that are *exactly* `12 months`. The following returns `true`:

```
select age('2000-12-31'::date, '2000-01-01'::date) = '12 months'::interval;

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

while this query returns `false`:

```
select '2000-12-31'::date - '12 months'::interval = '2000-01-01'::date;

 ?column? 
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

In fact:

```
select '2000-12-31'::date - '12 months'::interval;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 1999-12-31 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

while:

```
select age('2000-12-31'::date, '2000-01-01'::date);
       age       
-----------------
 11 mons 30 days
(1 row)
```

It is your choice to choose `age()` over `date - interval`. To solve this, you can use `>` against `>=`.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want rows from the `student` table, then this looks like you want an `exists` query:

```
select s.*
from student s
where exists (select * 
              from retake r
              where s.id = r.id --?? not sure about this, your example is unclear
              and s.examdate + interval '12' month <= r.retakedate)
```

Comment: yes i want rows from the student table only if the difference between the exam date and retake date is >=12months

Comment: @donjon did you try this query? Seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function AGE

```
select age( '01/10/2015', '11/12/2014')
```

will return result - 1 mon 28 days

combination with EXTRACT give You result in MONTHs

```
select EXTRACT (MONTH FROM age( '01/10/2015', '11/12/2014'))
```

result - 1

Full version after questions in comments:

```
select t1.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id 
WHERE
(EXTRACT (YEAR FROM age( t2.retakedate, t1.examdate))*12 +EXTRACT (MONTH FROM age( t2.retakedate, t1.examdate))) >= 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by working with subqueries.

You mentioned that there will be multiple rows in both tables. To always check the latest retake for one given exam, it would be advisable to also add an `exam_id` to both tables; otherwise the latest written exam might not be the one having the latest written retake.

For the sake of not having to put the rather long `date_diff` select into the `WHERE` clause, I put this part in a subquery as well. This query would return only John given the example data you posted above.

```
WITH latest_retake AS (

SELECT
id
,MAX(retakedate)    AS last_retakedate

FROM retake

GROUP BY 1

), latest_exam AS (

SELECT
id
,name
,MAX(examdate)  AS last_examdate

FROM student

GROUP BY 1,2

), date_diffs AS (

SELECT

le.id
,name
,last_examdate
,last_retakedate
,(DATE_PART('year', last_retakedate) - DATE_PART('year', last_examdate)) * 12 + (DATE_PART('month', last_retakedate) - DATE_PART('month', last_examdate)) AS date_diff

FROM latest_exam    le
JOIN latest_retake  lr  ON le.id = lr.id

)

SELECT 
*
FROM date_diffs

WHERE date_diff >= 12
```